# Why am I unable to update ipython?

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook

I'm unable to update the ipython on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. The actual installed version is 1.2.1

I've tried:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade ipython[all]
```

But it returns

```
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython[all] in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package
```

And the version remains the same. I'm not sure where I messed up.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you determining the installed version? Does `pip list` show ipython (1.2.1)?

Comment: I use:

     $ ipython --version

However, as you suggest pip list shows: ipython (3.1.0)

Comment: So your `$ which ipython` is not the ipython that `pip` installed.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Ubuntu package ipython is also installed so you have actually 2 versions of ipython installed. You can try to uninstall the Ubuntu package

```
sudo apt-get uninstall ipython
```

Then you might have to upgrade Ipython with pip.